# How to pass parameter to custom Action script in InstallShield?

Tags: installshield

I made the following script
"[SystemFolder]cmd.exe" /c "netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="RuleName" action=allow protocol=TCP dir=in localport=399"

and i made a dialog in setup that take the Port number and set it to a property called ServerPort ..
now my question  is how to pass this value to this script ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should change the property name to SERVER_PORT so it's public. Properties with lowercase letters do not pass their modified values to InstallExecuteSequence.

After that, you can try something like this:

```
"[SystemFolder]cmd.exe" /c "netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="RuleName" action=allow protocol=TCP dir=in localport=[SERVER_PORT]"
```

Comment: It should also be marked Secure.  BTW, if it was me, I'd create a WiX merge module and use the Firewall extension to do this.  The module can then be merged into the InstallShield project as I've described in my blog. http://blog.deploymentengineering.com/2011/01/augmenting-installshield-using-windows.html